# Printing a 2 dimensional constructor in Java

Tags: java, arrays, constructor, 2d

I'm need to print the values of the 2d array in the constructor from the main method. Everytime I call the *mainSc* array, I get a value of *null* for each value in the 2d array. Why is that and how do I fix the array to call values from the constructor?

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[][] mainSc = new String[5][5];

        System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(mainSc));
    }
}

import java.util.Arrays;

public class Schedule {
    private int numDays;
    private int numClasses;
    private String[][] Cal;

    public Schedule(String[][] array) {
        this.numDays = 5;
        this.numClasses = 4;
        this.Cal = array;
    }
    public String[][] Array() {
        for (int r = 0; r < numDays; r++){
            for (int j = 0; j <= numClasses; j++){
                this.Cal[0][0] = "Monday";
                this.Cal[1][0] = "Tuesday";
                this.Cal[2][0] = "Wednesday";
                this.Cal[3][0] = "Thursday";
                this.Cal[4][0] = "Friday";  
            }
        }
      return this.Cal;
    }
    public void printSchedule() {
        for (int r = 0; r <= numDays; r++){
            for (int j = 0; j <= numClasses; j++){
                System.out.println(this.Cal[r][j]);
            }
        }
    }
```

}

Comment: You obtain `null` because the array contain nothing. Then the JVM set the default value `null`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declaring an array reference variable does not create an array. The next step in the process is to use the **new** keyword to create an array and assign its address to the variable. You should also include the dimensions for the array.

```
private String[][] cal = new String[5][5];
```